# Generating the best exponential distribution with percentile constraints

Tags: python, statistics, distribution, exponential

Im trying to generate the best exponential distribution (fit wise)
that will have the following characteristics:

1.The range of the results is in [0,500]

2.The CDF percentiles as close to the following relation(.percentile,value)
  0.3-50,0.5-100, 0.8:200,0.9-300, 0.95-400, 1-500

First,I tried to get the lambda coefficient by the median constraint of 100 :
lambda=100/ln(2)= 0.006931 and than drawing the distribution:

```
data = np.random.exponential((1/0.006931), size=1000)
plt.hist(data,bins=30)
plt.show()
```

[image]

The re scaling to [0,500]

```
data=(data-min(data))/(max(data)-min(data))*500    
plt.hist(data,bins=30)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Than Im trying to re scale the results to 500  and plot the histogram and the CDF but Im pretty far from the red dots that resemble the percentile which I want to get close too with the distribution.

```
x = np.sort(data)
y = np.arange(1, len(x) +1) /len(x)
_ = plt.plot(x,y, marker ='.', linestyle='none')
x_percentile = np.array([0,50, 100, 200, 350, 400, 500])
y_percentile = np.array([0,30, 50, 80, 90, 95, 100])
plt.scatter(x_percentile, y_percentile/100,color='r')
plt.xlabel('results')
plt.ylabel('ECDF')
plt.show()
```

[image]

How can I find the closest distribution function for my problem?

Comment: It is not really a exponential distribution if it is constrained to being 0 after 500. Do you have the constrain that the CDF should be 0 at x=0 as well? The "best"/closest exponential distribution can maybe found by curve fitting to your target percentiles.

Comment: well yes its not classic exponential but it should look "exponential" in the range [0,500]

Comment: Have you checked my answer? Is that sufficient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can maybe use `scipy.optimize.curve_fit` to find the "best" exponential. Assuming you have a constraint that the CDF should be 0 at 0, i.e. the shift is 0, thus loc=0, we only need to fit the scale parameter (lambda):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import expon
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def fitfun(x, *a):
    ex = expon(loc=0, scale=a[0])
    return ex.cdf(x)

y = 0, 0.3, 0.5, 0.8, 0.9, 0.95, 1
x = 0, 50, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500
p, _ = curve_fit(fitfun, x, y, 100/np.log(2))
print(p[0]) # 133.99106748543082
solution = expon(loc=0, scale=p[0])

X = arange(600)
plt.plot(X, solution.cdf(X))
plt.plot(x, y, marker='o', ls='')
plt.show()
```

[image: exponental distribution fit]

Using `curve_fit` you could add uncertainties to the fit to make the constraint 0-0 and 1-500 in the CDF stronger than the other constraints, or use a different optimization routine. `curve_fit` will by default use least squares and Levenberg-Marquardt for fitting. This is just meant as an idea, not as a perfect solution.

Comment: Thanks!! And  how i can I plot a histogram of the new distribution?

Comment: Plot `solution.pdf(X)`. You can check out the scipy stats docs: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/stats.html If you like the answer, please accept (and upvote).

Comment: You can also draw `num` random variates from the distribution using `solution.rvs(size=num)`.

Comment: Thanks! Can I  limit  the random numbers generator by a maximum number of 500?

Comment: No, you can just sample again if you encounter a value > 500. This obviously biases your samples, but that is what you want.

Comment: You can also fold with a uniform distribution from zero to 500, which is basically the same result.